# Bcrypt stretches (with Devise) and Heroku dynos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, bcrypt

I am currently reviewing security of my admin model generated with Devise. It raises a lot of questions on how a web dyno at Heroku processes the password encription.

**first question :**

My default Devise setup for bcrypt cost is `config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11` Does it mean there are eleven stretches for the test environment ? It seems the default stretches is 11 and I can confirm my hash under development environment is 11 too. So why specifiying 11 for test ?

I plan raising to 12 with `config.stretches = 12`

**second question :**

If I raise the strectches, the encryption time will increase. Will it freeze my app and prevent other visitors to make http requests to the app ? How many concurrent http requests can be made to a web dyno and how many concurrent password encryption can also be made to a web dyno (if this is different).

My knowledge of dynos is not deep, but I know a worker dyno can thread multiple Sidekiq workers depending on the processor cores .. Though the dyno don't specify the number of cores, and I don't know if this apply to web dynos too.

Basically I know that raising strectches will increase encrypting time, yet will it affect the whole app efficiency ?

Answer (score 1):

`config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 11` will use just 1 for testing, otherwise 11. This is to speed up testing since there isn't any point in making passwords secure in a test environment.

If you plan to use 12, the use `config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 12`.

More stretches take more computation. Typically this won't be a performance concern, don't optimize or focus on this unless you spot a real problem.

Comment: Thanks Aromero, I will use your syntax, it does make sense to keep test to 1.

Answer (score 1):

That line in your config is short for

```
if Rails.env.test?
  config.stretches = 1
else
  config.stretches = 11
end
```

ie. in tests config.stretches is 1, the rest of the time it is 11.

Raising the number of stretches will indeed increase the amount of time it takes to hash a password. The stretches parameter increases time exponentially: changing it from 11 to 12 doubles the time, so yes it will reduce the number of requests your app can handle.

However, typically you only incur this cost during operations such as a user setting their password or logging in, which is only a small fraction of overall requests in general.

Comment: Thanks Frederick. I will keep hashing under one second I think. Yet as I can't async the login, I am still wondering how much of hashing a Heroku server can serve simultaneously. My app is not public yet, but when public I will monitor the dynos activity and try to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Author of `devise-async-stretch` here. It was built to do the password stretching in a background job queue.

I no longer actively use it (or maintain it) and would encourage it's use only if you're securing your redis connection (which most background processors rely on) with SSL.

https://github.com/danielwestendorf/devise-async-stretch

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for mentionning this gem. I will use it in case I have a lot of stretches. Yet I will still have to process the logins on the fly, so have to be moderate in terms of strecthes number.